# Multiple Regression with Repeated Measures?

Tags: linear-regression, repeat, measure, fpgrowth

So I am trying to analyze some seagrass recovery data where I measured shoot density monthly and I am trying to see if either depth and species or any combination contributes more to the recovery of the seagrass. I was thinking to do a multiple regression but is there a way to make it consider this was done monthly? Or should I just include month in the regression?

P.S. Data definitely lot normal

Comment: I personally would use "months since beginning data collection", so that the first month is 0 and the second month is 1, etc. and include it in the regression. This will not directly capture annual or seasonal variation, so processing of the now-numeric month data might be used to capture annual minimums and maximums.